# Error adding date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Needed some help solving why my dataframe is returning all NaNs.

```
print df
   0  1  2  3   4
0  1  9  0  7  30
1  2  8  0  4  30
2  3  5  0  3  30
3  4  3  0  3  30
4  5  1  0  3  30
```

Then I added date index. I only need to increment by one day for 5 days.

```
date = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime.today(), periods=5)
data = DataFrame(df, index=date)
print data

                             0   1   2   3   4
2014-04-10 17:16:09.433000 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2014-04-11 17:16:09.433000 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2014-04-12 17:16:09.433000 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2014-04-13 17:16:09.433000 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2014-04-14 17:16:09.433000 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Tried a few different things to no avail. If I switch my original dataframe to

```
 np.random.randn(5,5)
```

Then it works. Anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

Edit: Going to add that the data type is float64

```
print df.dtypes

0    float64
1    float64
2    float64
3    float64
4    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should overwrite the index of the original dataframe with the following:

```
df.index = date
```

What `DataFrame(df, index=date)` does is that it creates new dataframe by matching the values of `index` to the `df` being used, for example:

```
DataFrame(df, index=[0,1,2,5,5])
```

returns the following:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   1   9   0   7  30
1   2   8   0   4  30
2   3   5   0   3  30
5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

because `5` is not included in the index of the original dataframe.